# Отправка сообщения в канал Telegram средствами Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram, sendmessage

Прошу помочь со скриптом для отправки сообщений в канал телеграмма, все поиски приводят к созданию бота и его регистрации, бота я сделал, но это походу не то что мне надо, мне надо что скрипт отправлял текстовый пост в канал и все, возможно иногда и фото. python 3

Comment: Советую взглянуть на pyTelegramBotApi. [Тут](https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI) есть всё необходимое для начала и даже больше.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нет ничего проще! Для начала надо хотя бы кратко ознакомиться с **[bot api telegram](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api)** откуда мы возьмём необходимый нам в данном конкретном случае метод - **sendMessage**. Теперь надо определиться с выбором библиотеки python для работы с http, так как api telegram работает по http(s). Лично я, не мудрствуя лукаво, выбрал **requests**. Теперь приступаем к написанию функции отправки сообщения.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import requests

def send_telegram(text: str):
    token = "ТУТ_ВАШ_ТОКЕН_КОТОРЫЙ_ВЫДАЛ_BotFather"
    url = "https://api.telegram.org/bot"
    channel_id = "@ИМЯ_КАНАЛА"
    url += token
    method = url + "/sendMessage"

    r = requests.post(method, data={
         "chat_id": channel_id,
         "text": text
          })

    if r.status_code != 200:
        raise Exception("post_text error")

if __name__ == '__main__':
  send_telegram("hello world!")
```

Собсно, тут всё очень просто. Мы подставляем **token** своего бота выданный **botfather** в ссылку, далее через слеш указываем имя api метода и наконец вызываем метод **post** с помощью библиотеки **requests** куда подставляем текст сообщения и имя канала. Так же, если не ошибаюсь, бот должен быть администратором этого канала, чтоб там что-то постить.

Comment: Можно ли такую тему для Ватсапа реализовать как нибудь?