# Работа с telegram api без сторонних библиотек на Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram

необходимо собирать сообщения из своего телеграмма с помощью Python, но не использовать сторонних библиотек(таких как telethon).

Comment: Можно использовать библиотеку requests и посылать с её помощью запросы, например [вот](https://tproger.ru/translations/telegram-bot-create-and-deploy/) и [вот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/931492/%D0%9E%D1%82%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB-telegram-%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-python)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Отправка сообщения в канал Telegram средствами Python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/931492/%d0%9e%d1%82%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bb-telegram-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-python)

Comment: Но это для телеграм бота, а мне надо, допустим, получить сообщения из канала или из переписки с другом.

Comment: Как [указал](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1146707/%d0%a0%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0-%d1%81-telegram-api-%d0%b1%d0%b5%d0%b7-%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%85-%d0%b1%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba-%d0%bd%d0%b0-python#comment1985744_1146707) [@timur](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/391606/timur), берите `requests`, описание api телеги и пишите свое.